# How do I use epoll?

Tags: linux

I know that an interest in a file descriptor is registered with epoll_ctl, but I  can not find any info on how to actually use epoll.

If I want to read and write files asynchronously, how do I do it? Do I use the normal read and write calls? Do I call these functions before or after calling epoll_wait, and do I mark the file descriptors to be used as nonblock?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll which part you don't understand? generally, for every function, you can `man *func_name* to read about it.

Comment: about your async io stuff. if `epoll` returns the fd to you. it's guaranteed to be nonblocking. i don't see which point you are worrying about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing the concepts. `epoll(7)` is not the same thing as asynchronous I/O. `select(2)`, `poll(2)`, `epoll(7)` and other similar functions can block whether or not the underlying file descriptors are blocking or non-blocking; they provide a synchronous form of notification - the system doesn't tell you anything until you explicitly ask for it.

The point of `select(2)`, `poll(2)` and family is that you can do I/O multiplexing: with a single blocking call, you can wait for interesting events in a given set of file descriptors. This is *not* the same as asynchronous I/O.

POSIX asynchronous I/O, on the other hand, uses AIO control blocks to describe I/O operations (`struct aiocb`), and it is performed mostly with `aio_read(3)`, `aio_write(3)`, `aio_return(3)` and `aio_suspend(3)`. Unless you have a very good reason to do this, don't - it complicates the design quite a lot.

To use `epoll(7)`, there's really not much to say besides what you can read in `man 7 epoll`:

- Create an `epoll` instance with `epoll_create(2)` or the more recent variant `epoll_create1(2)`.
- Register interest in file descriptors with `epoll_ctl(2)`.
- Call `epoll_wait(2)` to wait for an I/O event, possibly blocking the calling thread until some event is available

Once `epoll_wait(2)` returns, assuming it was successful, you are guaranteed that at least one of the operations of interest that you previously registered with `epoll_ctl(2)` will not block. The events that will not block are returned by `epoll_wait(2)` in the buffer you fed it (the second argument to `epoll_wait(2)`).

Iterate through that buffer and figure out what you want to do. For example, if you registered interest in reading a file descriptor and it was returned by `epoll_wait(2)` (the `events` field for that entry includes `EPOLLIN`), then you can call `read(2)` knowing that it won't block. The same goes true for `write(2)`, but only if you registered interest in knowing when a `write(2)` won't block, and that event was returned by `epoll_wait(2)`.

So, yes, you call `read(2)` / `write(2)` after `epoll_wait(2)`, but make sure that you perform an operation that was actually identified as being available, so that you don't block.

Oh, and remember that `epoll(7)` is Linux-specific.

Comment: Thanks, you're right I've mixed up some concepts. So to do async reads on multiple files for example without the posix thing, I'd use epoll_wait (blocking is fine here) to wait on file descriptors being ready for reads. Then I would read on those that are avilable, making sure the file descriptors have O_NONBLOCK set so that the read operations don't block, and then I'd epoll_wait again to wait for the read results? Something like that?

Comment: @Storm You're almost there. After calling `epoll_wait(2)`, you read on those that are available. The descriptors don't necessarily need `O_NONBLOCK`. You iterate through the events array and test if the `events` field of each entry contains `EPOLLIN`. If it does, you are guaranteed that read won't block, whether or not the descriptor is in non-blocking mode, because data is available to read. So, in short, you just call `epoll_wait()` and read, knowing that you can't block. There's no 2nd `epoll_wait()` to "wait for the results".

Comment: @Storm Note that the `events` field of `struct epoll_event` is a bit set that describes multiple events, so to test if it's available to read you need `if (ep_events.events & EPOLLIN) { /* Safe to read... */ }`, assuming `ep_events` is the array returned by `epoll_wait(2)`.

Comment: Right but the data may take time to read and on a high throughput server for example that does not use a thread per connection I'd want to do something else on that same thread in the meanwhile, thus the O_NONBLOCK. I'd use epoll_wait to tell me when the read has finished.

Comment: @Storm If reading per se is too expensive, `epoll` is not going to help much. `O_NONBLOCK` will not help either, because that controls whether `read(2)` blocks *waiting* for data. If data is available to read, reading it will always take some time and you have to wait. If you want to do things in the same thread while reading, you're pretty much stuck with POSIX async I/O (more specifically, `aio_read(3)`). See `man 7 aio` and `man 3 aio_read`. Be aware that async I/O is inherently hard to get right, make sure there's really no other choice.